# R Data Table special reshape

Tags: r

I have data as below

```
AA  BB  CC
123 908 900
456 780 890
829 321 892
234 544 799
```

Want to display it as below

```
1   AA  123
1   BB  908
1   CC  900
2   AA  456
2   BB  780
2   CC  890
3   AA  829
3   BB  321
3   CC  892
4   AA  234
4   BB  544
4   CC  799
```

Thanks

Comment: What is special about that reshape? Just use `melt` if it is a "data.table"....

Comment: `tidyr::gather(DT, var, value)`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(reshape)

df <- data.frame(AA=c(123, 456, 829, 234), BB=c(908, 780, 321, 544), CC=c(900, 890, 892, 799))
```

[image]

```
df_b <- melt(t(df))[c(1,3)]
```

[image]

Rename columns as needed.